# JAVA AWS S3 multipart upload with inputstream and length of inputstream is unknown

Tags: java, amazon-s3, upload, vaadin

If content length is unknown then AmazonS3Client and TransferManager buffers the content in the memory,it results in out of memory exception.

So i wanted to go with multipart upload(Low Level of API).
But i didn't find ways to upload with inputstream(Examples are there with File).
I tried by passing inputstream but no result.
My Code :: (Inside Vaadin upload receiver)

```
@Override
public OutputStream receiveUpload(final String filename, String mimeType) {
    this.fileName=filename;
    PipedOutputStream pos=null;
    try {
        pos= new PipedOutputStream();
        final InputStream is = new PipedInputStream(pos);
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
                    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(
                                                                        bucketName, filename);
                    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = 
                                                  s3.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
                    long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // Set part size to 5 MB.
                    int size = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    int len=0;
                    int partNum = 1;
                     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    for(int i=1;(len=is.read(buffer,0,size))!=-1;i++){
                        bos.write(buffer,0,len); 
                        if(bos.size()>=partSize){
                            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                            .withBucketName(bucketName).withKey(filename)
                            .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(partNum++)
                            .withInputStream(is)
                            .withPartSize(partSize);
                             partETags.add(
                                        s3.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());
                            bos.flush();
                            bos.close();
                            ins.close();
                            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        }
                    }
                    //rest of data, written to s3
                    System.out.println("After remaining bos "+bos.size());
                    UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucketName).withKey(filename)
                    .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(partNum++)
                    .withInputStream(is)
                    .withLastPart(true);
                    partETags.add(
                            s3.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartETag());

                    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new 
                                 CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
                                            bucketName, 
                                            filename, 
                                            initResponse.getUploadId(), 
                                            partETags);

                    s3.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pos;
}
```

> .withInputStream(is)
>   here I'm passing original stream or do i need to create a temp stream
>   with read content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes I did by modifying the easyuploads vaadin addon. Implemented a reciever which has file size as one more parameter.